# Check Previous Step If Status Is Done And Display If The Next Process If It's Finish

Tags: mysql, sql, select

We have different process such as **Designing, Sample, Mock Up, Letterpress, Tracing, Printing**. But a certain job can do any job randomly.
I want to select **Printing** process but before that I want to check if the previous process are already done.

I want to check the previous step if already done if done show the next process.

Status Meaning:
**1** is equal to **FINISH**
**0** is equal to **NOT YET FINISH**

I use the following query but it won't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM process
WHERE status = 0
AND (SELECT * FROM process WHERE step=step-1 AND status=1)
```

PROCESS TABLE

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|    ID     | Job Code |  Job Name  |   Step    |  Status  |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| 1         | J0003    | Designing  | 0         | 1        |
| 2         | J0003    | Sample     | 1         | 1        |
| 3         | J0003    | Printing   | 2         | 0        |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

RESULT:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| 3         | J0003    | Printing   | 2         | 0        |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

This should be the result because the first and second step are already done. Done, why because the row `status` has a value of 1.

If the value of status of the second process **Sample** is equal to 0 then the result is nothing or display empty.

Comment: you can increase a column and update it when the service is user with its order.

Comment: "I want to select Printing process but before that I want to check if the previous process are already done."  Is the previous process "Tracing"?  If so, why don't I see that in your query?

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: @GordonLinoff. The tracing I used is the row `step`. And I already possible result  above sir.

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav. I add the possible result above sir.

Comment: I mean you need to display only NOT YET FINISH process according to your expected result.

Comment: How do you know these all relate to the same sequence? Shouldn't the JobCode be the same?

Comment: Yeah my fault they are related by `jobcode` that the sequence `step` are connected. Sorry for typographical error on it @KeithL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your query would do what you want if you used qualified column names:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM process p
WHERE p.status = 0 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM process p2 WHERE p2.step = p.step - 1 AND p2.status = 1);
```

Comment: When there are so many data and the job name **Printing** are in different step number not 1 it couldn't be find it only find the item where step value is equal to 1. The following data samle are at https://github.com/Ailyn09/project102/blob/master/process.txt

Comment: Thanks for the EXISTING and now I got what I need. By the way I use `SELECT *
FROM process p1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM process p2 WHERE p2.processnum = p1.processnum - 1 AND p2.status = 1)
AND p1.status = 0 AND p1.jobname='Printing';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM process p1 WHERE p1.status = 0 AND
     p1.id not in (SELECT p2.id FROM process p2 WHERE p2.step = p1.step - 1 AND p2.status = 1);
```